# Visual Studio builds are reverting code to pre-correction states

Tags: visual-studio, build, asp.net-core-mvc, revert

So, new to .NET Core and going slow. Followed a standard tutorial for ASP.NET Core MVC app using Entity Framework to connect to MSSQLLocalDB - this went well.

Converted the application to connect to MySql, and went equally well,
Changed the name of a table on MySql to Interests from Interest, and after a bit of fiddling around this to was put to bed, that is it was working as expected.

Went to run the application today and I get:

> There were Build Errors Would you like to continue and run the last successfull build.

Code has reverted to Interest, from Interests in several places in Obj files,
for instance "Create.cshtml.g.cs"

Corrected the code and went to run, the same build error pops up, and all corrections are undone.
I make the changes again, save the files, exit VS, reload, the changes are as they should be, run and it reverts all changes, failing again.

I thought this might be some sort of cache issue so deleted the obj folder, again corrected the entries, but again run the build and the corrections reverted!

Comment: One thing I did do in between was install some extensions, that I have used over long time and not expected a problem, however removing them and relaoding seems to have fixed the issue. Wont say case closed just yet though.

Comment: I would also like to know this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue on my machine by changing the cshtml file properties. Right click the chstml file in the Solution Explorer window, click on Properties in the context menu.Then in the Properties window, change the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". Then make sure "Build Action" is set to "Content".